# there's an error to createElement and its attribute

Tags: javascript

I try to createElement as h1 and its attribute class, but i can not get it working.

here goes my post:

```
function krea_ta(){
  var tagy = document.cteateElement("h1");
  var clasy = createAttribute("class");
  clasy.value = "myclass";
  tagy.setAttributeNode(clasy);
  tagy.innerText = "business";
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why not just write `tagy.className = "myclass";`

Comment: Also, what exactly is the error?

Comment: Did you leave out `document.` before `createAttribute("class")` ?

Comment: typos:  add `document` and spell `create` and it works

Answer (score 3):

First things first, you've spelled "create" wrong on "createElement".

Secondly, you can either set the class as an attribute using `tagy.setAttribute("class", "myclass")`

or via the `classList` property which expects an array of strings..

`tagy.classList = ["myclass"];`

---

Edit:

The above assign of the array might not be working on all browsers (works on Chrome), as MDN states that classList is a read-only property.

`tagy.classList.add(["myclass"]);`

The `.add` method accepts parameterised values, array of values and a single value.

Comment: Never seen this usage of `classList` before. Is it better to assign an array instead of using the `add` method?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I'd use the `.add` method actually. According to documentation, it's a read-only property meaning I need to change my code now too because I've assigned directly to the property as recently as today... :) (Just tested in IE, direct assigning doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do it like this:

```
    function krea_ta(){
      const tagy = document.createElement("h1");
      const tagyText = document.createTextNode("business");
      tagyText.appendChild(tagyText);
      tagy.classList.add("myClass");
      document.body.appendChild(tagy);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the whole all above it does not work.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Everything I wrote should work just fine.

Comment: looks works with console.log(), but in the site the text still it does not appear.

Comment: I've edited my original answer, if you've not sorted the issue by now, you can try that!

Comment: Even i'v copied your post, it does not work and I look in console, it say;

Comment: her go the answer of console; HierarchyRequestError: The operation would yield an incorrect node tree. appendChild-Creat_Attribute_02.html  & area_ta-Creat_Attribute_02.html

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad. I've edited my post again and the code now works, I've just tested it myself.

Comment: For me, still I don't get it and I've same error massage like before in console.